# What does 劲抽 mean?

Tags: grammar

I was looking at a Chinese poster for the new Suicide Squad movie:

http://screenrant.com/suicide-squad-posters-international-joker/

I saw the phrase '各有各劲抽.'  What does this mean?  'Each one has powers,' or something like that?

Thank you,
Rachel

Comment: something like that:see http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/40226/ 勁抽  ging6 cau1   = powerful, excellent (also 勁秋)

Comment: "kick ass" .... I can't think of any better translation ~~~ lol ~~~~

Comment: It is Cantonese not Mandarin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well, it's a popular slang in hong kong, most of the time it's "勁揪"; however, when one say it, the pronunciation of "揪" is slightly changed to "抽"

[sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/ging6.Mp3),[sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/cau1.Mp3)

"kick ass", "smash", "rock" are some possible translations.

[勁 (u+52c1)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8B%81) is "strong, powerful, sturdy"

[揪 (u+63ea)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%8F%AA) is "to fight"

so, it's roughly "good at fighting" --> "wonderful, powerful".

[抽 (u+62bd)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%8A%BD), is "pull, levy, whip"; which has the syllable of what we pronounce; and, 抽 is more common, civilised.

so "各有各勁抽" in the poster, roughly means "members are good at fighting individually"

if you pronounce it correctly, you're 勁揪

[image: p1]

have fun :)

Comment: +1 for 勁揪 written with a brush. Is there a name for this style of writing?

Comment: indeed, currently (summer 2016) there's a fundraising project to make a 勁揪 font, have a look of this : http://kickasstype.crowdfundhq.com/campaigns/xn--4ersft7x38ipocs57cjduselrox